# In ios 6, how do you use pass data between View controller holding 'Container View' object and Table View controller that is embedded in it?

Tags: ios, view, containers

I have a view controller with a label and textfield. I also added a container view which points to another table view controller with one section and 3 rows, basically static table view. I am unable to find any documentation / example which tells you how you pass data between View controller holding the Container View and Table View container embedded in the container view. I want both sided communication ?

Answer (score 8):

The controller embedded in the container view (in storyboard), is automatically added as a childViewController of the controller in which the container view is added. Just to make sense of what I mean, add this line, in your viewDidLoad method of the base controller :

```
NSLog(@"children : %@", self.childViewControllers);
```

So lets say in VC1, you add a container view with an embedded controller VC2 (your tableViewController), then the above statement will log VC2 as a child of VC1. To access VC2 from VC1, you just use **[self.childViewControllers objectAtIndex:0]**, and to access VC1 from VC2, just use self.parentViewController.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

If you set things up in a storyboard, you use segues. Just like most everything else in storyboards.

See [Access Container View Controller from Parent iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13279105/access-container-view-controller-from-parent-ios)

Answer (score 0):

There are new properties on UIViewController -childViewControllers and -parentViewController. You could use those.

Alternatively you could set up a relationship yourself. Be weary of retain cycles. Perhaps the parent owns the child and the child has a weak reference back to the parent.

Answer (score 0):

`[self.childViewControllers lastOject]` or `[self.childViewControllers objectAtIndex:index];` , depending upon how many child VC's you have.