# UIStoryboard Container Attach IBOutlet To Parent ViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, iboutlet

I wanted to use a `UITableView` which contained static cells with a `UITextField` inside attached to my `LoginViewController`. I have added `IBOutlets` in the header file that correspond to the `UITextFields` in the storyboard. Unfortunately Xcode does not allow static content inside a `UITableView` you need to use a `UITableViewController`.

Therefore I split out the `UITableView` from the storyboard and used a `ContainerView` to embed a `UITableViewController` which works well. Attached a screenshot of the setup.

[image: Current Storyboard Setup]

The problem I am now facing is I cannot link the `UITextFields` to my `LoginViewController`, you can see from my screenshot that I have added an `Object` to the `UITableViewController` which I have set to my `LoginViewController` and managed to link the `UITextFields` to it. But when the main view loads it says my `UITextFields` are `nil`

**How can I link my `UITextFields` to my `IBOutlets` in my `LoginViewController`?**

Edit:
If I have to subclass the `UITableViewController` it seems like I should have just used a prototype cell... Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.) Name your embed segue to "TextFields"

2.) If you haven't already, subclass `UITableViewController` and set your table view controller to this class in the storyboard. Let's call it `TextFieldsTableViewController`.

3.) Again, if you haven't already, add `IBOutlet`s for your text fields into `TextFieldsTableViewController`'s public interface:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *firstNameField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *usernameField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *emailField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *passwordField;
```

4.) Add properties for your text fields into your `LoginViewController`'s public interface (note that unlike the above, these are not weak (they are also not `IBOutlet`s, but that doesn't really matter)):

```
@property (nonatomic) UITextField *firstNameField;
@property (nonatomic) UITextField *usernameField;
@property (nonatomic) UITextField *emailField;
@property (nonatomic) UITextField *passwordField;
```

5.) In `LoginViewController`'s `prepareForSegue:sender:` method, map the `TextFieldsTableViewController`'s text fields to `self`'s text fields after forcing the table view controller's view to load immediately:

```
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"TextFields"]) {

    TextFieldsTableViewController *textFieldsVC = segue.destinationViewController;

    // IMPORTANT: This forces the view to load and the outlets to get set.
    // If you don't do this, textFieldsVC's IBOutlets will all be nil at this point.
    // This is slightly inelegant in my opinion, but it works. A better solution might
    // be to set the text fields in TextFieldsTableViewController's viewDidLoad method.
    [textFieldsVC view];

    self.firstNameField = textFieldsVC.firstNameField;
    self.usernameField = textFieldsVC.usernameField;
    self.emailField = textFieldsVC.emailField;
    self.passwordField = textFieldsVC.passwordField;
}
```

6.) You should now be able to access the text fields in `LoginViewController`'s `viewDidLoad` method.

Comment: Looks like this could do the job. Shame that you have to subclass the `UITableViewController` :S

Answer (score 1):

Since progressing in the project, I have learnt that it would have been better to not use a static UITableView seeing as you can get into complications like this quickly.

If you were really against doing any subclassing you can add this to the `viewDidAppear:` method - (Because the UITableView didn't load any cells at `viewWillAppear:`

```
[self.childViewControllers enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    UIViewController *childViewController = obj;
    //Make sure we are using the correct view controller -
    if([childViewController.restorationIdentifier isEqualToString:@"LoginTableViewController"]){
        self.username = (UITextField *)[childViewController.view viewWithTag:-2];
        self.email = (UITextField *)[childViewController.view viewWithTag:-3];
        self.password = (UITextField *)[childViewController.view viewWithTag:-4];
    }
}];
```

Just make sure to tag your views in the `Storyboard`.

W