# Passing data back from embedded view controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, swift, uitextfield, ios8

I have a `UIViewController` which embedded inside another `UIViewController`. In this child view controller, there are two `UITextField`s which lets the user to enter some data.

How can I pass that data entered in that embedded view controller back to the parent view controller?

I tried to get a reference to the text fields in the child view controller using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13280508/1077789) method but I get an error.

```
let textfield: UITextField = self.childViewControllers.last?.usernameTextField! as UITextField
```

This `usernameTextField` is one of the `UITextField`s inside that embedded `UIViewController`. I get the following error,

**'AnyObject' does not have a member named 'usernameTextField'**

Is this the best way to do this or are there any other routes I could take to accomplish this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to typecast before using it. Check with:

```
let myObj : MyClass        = self.childViewControllers.last as ? MyClass;
let textfield: UITextField = myObj?.usernameTextField! as UITextField;
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked. Although I didn't need that `?` when casting to the `UITextField`.