# How do I delegate a UITableViewController with static cells which embed with a container inside UIViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, delegates

I have a UIViewController in my storyboard. Inside this UIViewController, I have a container which embed with a tableViewController. This tableViewController is a static table. How can I use this tableViewController inside UIViewController?

I have set protocols like `UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource` and I have no idea how I can get that tableViewController and delegate to my UIViewController.

Below are the screen.

P.S. I was trying to make a side navigation bar. Please notify me if you need to see any code.

[image]

Comment: you can use UIViewController as parent ViewController and tableViewController as childViewController. But better solution is to use UITableView in UIViewController as a subView.

Comment: Since it is a static table, I cannot put it in the UIViewController. There will be error when I build it. That's why I'm putting a container view inside the UIViewController and embed with a tableViewController. It seems like the parent ViewController way will work. But can you tell me more about it?

Comment: @SandeepKumar Thanks Kumar it works like a charm!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my opinion: create a delegate for your tableViewController like

```
@protocol SideTableViewContollerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)didClickCellOfIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

@end

@interface SideTableViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) id<SideTableViewContollerDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

and inside your UIViewController, you set the controller as the tableViewController's delegate

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"go table view"]) {
       SideTableViewController *stvc = (SideTableViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
       stvc.delegate = self;
   }
}
```

and inside the tableView's delegate function "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" do:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
   [self.delegate didClickCellOfIndexPath:indexPath];
   [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

and all that left is implementing tableView controller's delegate in the uiview controller

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I have to set the class in the embed tableViewController and put the `[self addChildViewController: myTableViewController]` in the UIViewController class. And I can implement in the UITableViewController class to control it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use segue to access the tableViewController. Just implement `- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender` and it will be called before viewController's viewDidLoad. See this answer: [Access Container View Controller from Parent iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13279105/access-container-view-controller-from-parent-ios)