# iOS Accessing PageViewController children inside ContainerView

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller, uicontainerview

I have a ViewController (let's call it MainViewController) that contains a ContainerView.  The ContainerView contains only one child - a PageViewController.  The PageViewController pages through 4 different ViewControllers (let's call them Red, Blue, Green, and Orange ViewControllers).  How would I access the various colored child ViewControllers from the MainViewController (each one contains a UITableView and I'd like to pass the data for those tableviews down from the MainActivity so that I don't have to make separate database calls to get the data from each one of the colored pages)?

Note: I know how to access a ViewController inside a ContainerView using this method: [Access Container View Controller from Parent iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13279105/access-container-view-controller-from-parent-ios) .  But that would only get me to the PageViewController - I need to go a level deeper than that.  An answer in Swift would be greatly appreciated.

Here's a screenshot to illustrate.
[image]

And as a follow-on, how would I access the MainViewController from the 4 colored "grand-children" ViewControllers (correct terminology?)?

Comment: Check out this tutorial https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/12/23/swift-uipageviewcontroller-tutorial/

Comment: I actually used that tutorial to learn PageViewControllers.  But it doesn't explain in that tutorial how to access the children of the PageViewController.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the previous answer pointed, this is a valid way to view the children:

```
if let myViewControllers = myPageViewController.viewControllers as? [UIViewController] {
    for viewController in myViewControllers {
        // Do something with the viewController
    }
}
```

But it will only show the one child that is currently in view.  If you want to access all the child `ViewControllers`, including the ones that aren't visible, when you instantiate and add them to the `ContainerView`/`PageViewController`, save a reference to them.  You can then use that reference to access any function/data inside of each child `ViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

On `UIPageViewController`, you have a property called [`viewControllers`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIPageViewController/viewControllers). It gives you `The view controllers displayed by the page view controller.`. It's an array, because an `UIPageViewController` could display multiple pages at the same time. But if you have only one page at the same time, the array will contain only this page.

Here is an example:

```
if let myViewControllers = myPageViewController.viewControllers as? [UIViewController] {
    for viewController in myViewControllers {
        // Do something with the viewController
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. So I assume I would first gai access to the PageViewController via the prepareForSegue function in the MainViewController, then I would use that reference to PageViewController to get the array of child view controllers?  I will give it a shot first thing tomorrow morning.

Comment: Julien, myPageViewController.viewControllers is returning an array of size 1, despite the fact that there are clearly multiple ViewControllers as children (I'm swiping through them as I type this...).  Any advice on this?

Comment: Yes, that's right. It gives you an array of the *visibles* viewcontrollers (in your case: 1). If you want to find all the viewcontrollers (even those who are not displayed), you have to request your data source yourself.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "request your data source yourself"?