# How to access properties from another ViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, properties, containers

I have a `ViewController` and another one which is a `TableViewController`. So I have the tableview in a container view in the `ViewController`. Moreover I have a button which will save the values from the tableview. But how do I access these values? I've uploaded a screenshot so you can imagine it better :)

[image: screenshot]

Comment: you mean when you click on the button which is on cell ,you have to save cell title in viewcontroller ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you use a container in this case.

But, have a look in

```
self.childViewControllers
```

It should contain your tableViewController.

Comment: because its an static cell table... and it needs to be in a UITableViewController...

Answer (score 0):

You make an IBOutlet. Go to the storyboard and drag your embedded tableView into your other view controller. There you can reference all of its exposed stuff (in the .h), assuming its been loaded already.

Reference on outlets: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Outlets/Outlets.html

Good post on using container views:
[IBOutlet link to embedded view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12676660/iboutlet-link-to-embedded-view-controller)