# IBOutlet for element in containerview inside original viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uicontainerview

In my main view I have two containers that have an IBOutlet in view controller.

In both the containers I have a an image and a label as in the picture below.

[image]

I want to have an IBOutlet to change the image and label but when I drag it to the original view controller it doesn't allow it.

So in the viewcontroller.swift as I said I can access each container by clicking and dragging. Like this

```
@IBOutlet weak var containerview1: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var containerview2: UIView!
```

But I am trying to access the image view and labels in the container, something like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var containerview1: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var containerview2: UIView!

@IBOutlet weak containerview1_ImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak containerview2_ImageView!: UIImageView!
```

I understand that this is probably not the correct way to do it. I need to be able to change the image and label in both of the container views programmatically through `viewcontroller.swift`.

Comment: Do you want your both container views (image, label) in one viewController ? Given image showing other two viewcontroller with segue.

Comment: I am not sue I understand you question. That is my actual storyboard. I need the viewcontroller.swift to be able to update the pictures and the labels in both the other containerviews.

Comment: i am seeing here three viewControllers.

Comment: The other two view controller are part of the conatinerview and are automatically created when you drop the containerview in. If you want to think of it that way, I am trying to set the elements of the second two view controllers from the first,

Comment: Oh. i create a solution. not sure now to give it as answer. You just need outlets in main view controller? Will i post the solution as answer?

Comment: container views are just UIView or something else?

Comment: They are just UIView

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IBOutlet link to embedded view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12676660/iboutlet-link-to-embedded-view-controller)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create two separate class for containers

```
import UIKit

class ContainerView1: UIView {
 
    @IBOutlet var containerView1Label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var containerView1ImageView: UIImageView!
}

class ContainerView2: UIView {

    @IBOutlet var containerView2Label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var containerView2ImageView: UIImageView!
}
```

In main viewController storyboard define those class

[image]

Now set the label and imageview outlet by dragging from storyboard

[image]

Now drag container outlets in main view controller and use

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var containerView1: ContainerView1!
    @IBOutlet var containerView2: ContainerView2!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    
    
    // use like this both container elements
    
    containerView1.containerView1Label.text = "Container view 1 lable"
    //containerView1.containerView1ImageView.image = yourImage file
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Comment: Awesome thank you  so much @SMi !. I was completely about to do it incorrectly, that is so much easier than I thought. Thanks again

Comment: I am getting the error "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping the optional value" on this line: containerView1.containerView1Label.text = "Container view 1 lable".   The only part of your explanation I didn't understand was when you wrote: "In main viewController storyboard define those class". I think that may be the problem.

Comment: "In main viewController storyboard define those class" by this i mean those UIView recognise ContainView1 class through storyboard when you dragging outlet of the container to ViewController class.I have created a demo project for this. and in my side it is working without error. If you give your mail address i can mail it.